# ruby exec use functions from my ~/.bashrc

Tags: ruby, bash, exec

In my `~/.bashrc`, I have a function:

```
function sayHi() {
    echo "hi, $@"
}
```

and in Ruby I want to:

```
`sayHi "friend"`
```

however, `sayHi` is "not found" in whatever context ruby runs `exec` or `system`.

How could I get Ruby to use functions in my `.bashrc`?

Comment: Who is your Ruby process currently running as?

Comment: `whoami` outputs my current user, so it must just be a matter of sourcing my bashrc for ruby's use

Comment: Does running `source ~/.bashrc` from Ruby first fix it?

Comment: that won't help unless OP prefixes it to every command, @alex.

Comment: after running `\`source ~/.bashrc\`` i get a "source not found"

Comment: bash man page: "When an interactive shell that is not a login shell is started, bash reads and executes commands from ~/.bashrc, if that file exists."

Comment: @MarkReed Yeah, just wondering if it would work to eliminate any other possible issues before finding a real solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `.bashrc` is only run for interactive shells. When you execute a command using backquotes in Ruby, it does not execute the command in an interactive shell.

You can force an interactive shell by running `bash -i`. For example, to run your command under an interactive shell, use:

```
`bash -ic 'sayHi "friend"'`
```

Comment: Even interactively, the `.bashrc` is only run by `bash` when invoked as `bash`.  Ruby seems to use `sh`, irrespective of the value of `$SHELL`.

Comment: @MarkReed Yes, backquotes in ruby are similar to the `system` call in the C library, which calls `/bin/sh -c` to execute the command. Since you want to explicitly run `bash`, not `sh`, and force an interactive shell, you need to run `bash` from within the backquotes with the `-i` flag. There are no languages that I know of which have backquotes or a `system()` call that use the value of `$SHELL`, because then the execution of the script would depend on the user's setting of `$SHELL`.